# main.cpp:20:10: fatal error: activemq/library/ActiveMQCPP.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

Tags: c++, cms, activemq

En Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS tengo que integrar un **cliente CMS** como productor y consumidor de **colas** del broker **ActiveMQ Artemis** en un proyecto en **C++**. Mi compañero de trabajo ya arrancó un broker ActiveMQ Artemis. 
Mi objetivo es poder compilar y ejecutar el código de ejemplo: https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/example, pero me sale el error:

> main.cpp:20:10: fatal error: activemq/library/ActiveMQCPP.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio

Puse este comando de compilación: [g++ -o main -pthread -I ../main main.cpp ../../src/main/.libs/libactivemq-cpp.a -luuid -I /usr/include/apr-1.0/ -lssl -lcrypto -lapr-1](https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/developers/building)
Previamente seguí los pasos de la página oficial para la instalación: https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/developers/building, también probé a instalar las dependencias solo con comandos:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade

sudo apt install default-jdk
#java -version

sudo apt install maven
#mvn -version

sudo apt-get install uuid uuid-dev
#apt-cache search libuuid

sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev
#apt list --installed build-essential libcppunit libcppunit-dev

sudo apt-get install libapr1 libapr1-dev

sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool

#Descargar CMS Client ActiveMQ de https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/download/395-release
tar xvjf activemq-cpp-library-3.9.5-src.tar.bz2
cd activemq-cpp-library-3.9.5
./configure
make
sudo make install
#activemqcpp-config --version

#Descargar ActiveMQ Artemis de https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/
tar -xzf apache-artemis-2.31.0-source-release.tar.gz
cd apache-artemis-2.31.0
mvn clean install
```

Comment: Ya conseguí compilar. Ahora me falta que se comunique con el broker con un usuario, contraseña, ip y puerto determinados y lo pueda ver en el panel de administración de ActiveMQ antes de intentar integrarlo en el proyecto.

Comment: Si pudiste resolver el problema, considera crear una respuesta contando cómo lo hiciste.

Comment: Al final pude compilar, pero ahora tengo problema con la conexión al broker ActiveMQ Artemis: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605731/conexi%c3%b3n-con-broker-activemq-artemis-usando-cliente-cms-en-c