# Problema conexión con broker ActiveMQ Artemis usando cliente CMS en C++

Tags: c++, cms, activemq

Intento conectar un **cliente CMS** en **C++** con el **broker ActiveMQ Artemis** como productor y consumidor de colas. He modificado el código de ejemplo: https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/example, introduciendo la ip, el puerto, el usuario y la contraseña proporcionado por el compañero que montó el broker usando la opción tcp.

```
//Tanto en el productor como en el consumidor
virtual void run() {
    ...
    connection = connectionFactory->createConnection("usuario", "contraseña");
    ...
}
...
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ...
    //He cambiado la ip y el puerto que puse realmente en el código por texto
    std::string brokerURI = "tcp://ip:puerto";
    ...
    bool useTopics = false;
}
```

Pero he comprobado que la ejecución se detiene en la instrucción `consumer = session->createConsumer(destination);`:

```
class HelloWorldConsumer : public ExceptionListener,
                           public MessageListener,
                           public Runnable {
    ...
    virtual void run() {
        ...
        //Aquí se detiene la ejecución, si pongo un mensaje después, no se muestra
        consumer = session->createConsumer(destination);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

En un principio tuve problemas de compilación: [main.cpp:20:10: fatal error: activemq/library/ActiveMQCPP.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605231/main-cpp2010-fatal-error-activemq-library-activemqcpp-h-no-existe-el-archiv?noredirect=1#comment1068304_605231), que lo solucioné de la siguiente forma (la única que me funcionó):
Me cloné el repositorio https://github.com/apache/activemq-cpp que indica la página https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/download/395-release y copié las carpetas *activemq, cms y decaf* del directorio *activemq-cpp/activemq-cpp/src/main* a la ubicación */usr/include*:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/activemq-cpp.git
cd activemq-cpp/activemq-cpp/src/main
sudo cp -r -t /usr/include activemq cms decaf
```

También modifiqué el comando de compilación de la página https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/developers/building, apartado Example por:
`g++ -o main -pthread -I ../main main.cpp /usr/local/lib/libactivemq-cpp.a -luuid -I /usr/include/apr-1.0/ -lssl -lcrypto -lapr-1`

Comment: Ya me ha dicho mi compañero que era algún problema desconocido de configuración del broker ActiveMQ Artemis o alguna otra cosa. Me ha demostrado que funciona, pero solo en local con el localhost. Que él recibía un log de un mensaje raro de error en el broker.